# Mapping a JSON Api to a Model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activemodel

I have access to a JSON API and would like to map the API to some classes in my Rails 3.2.1 model, thus I don't need any datatabse.

Example :
The API returns the current user with the following JSON
    {"first_name":"John","last_name":"Smith"}

I'd like to create a new User from that JSON.
I read that I can use Active Model.

Basically I'd like to do :

```
user = User.new.from_json '{"first_name":"John","last_name":"Smith"}'
Rails.logger.debug user.attributes[:first_name]
Rails.logger.debug user.attributes['first_name']
Rails.logger.debug user.first_name
```

It should print "John" three times.

I use this class

```
class User
  include ActiveModel::Serializers::JSON
  attr_accessor :attributes
end
```

but it does not work at all.
If I do a user.to_yaml, it returns

```
--- !ruby/object:User
attributes: John
```

Any idea ?

Thanks

Geoffroy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out the following,

```
user = User.new.from_json('{"first_name":"John","last_name":"Smith"}', false)
```

If that didn't solve your problem, following should, because internally `from_json` method uses `ActiveSupport::JSON.decode`

```
User.new(ActiveSupport::JSON.decode('{"first_name":"John","last_name":"Smith"}'))
```

Comment: Many thanks!

    user = User.new.from_json('{"first_name":"John","last_name":"Smith"}', false)

does the trick.

The only problem I have is

    Rails.logger.debug user.first_name

fails : NoMethodError (undefined method `first_name' for #<User:0x007fdefcaae348>)

Comment: It seems like something wrong with the accesser method for first_name attribute in your user class.